# SOAP API RequestTemplate Envelope Recipients no signinggroup info

Tags: docusignapi

I know this has been asked before, but is there any update on why the Recipients in the template returned by that call do not have any info on SigningGroupId?  The docs say they should.  I don't want to use the REST API for this one thing, so if I can't use SOAP, how can I get the Signing Group ID through the web interface so that I can provide it to the envelope creation through SOAP?

Answer (score 0):

The SOAP API doesn't have the option to create or manage signing groups, so it does not have an equivalent to the "SigningGroups: list" API call available for REST.

You can get the ID from the web by going to Settings > Signing Groups > "Your group" > actions > edit

The ID should appear on "Signing Group ID"

[image: Edit signing group page]

If you are building a new integration keep in mind that the REST API does allow you to create and edit the signing groups so it may be a better option for your integration